# make webserver from Ubuntu 14.04 desktop version in virtualbox

Tags: linux, web-services, ubuntu, server, virtualbox

I'm thinking about creating a webserver from my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on virtualbox. I've made some test pages there but I have no idea how to connect from my computer (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well) to virtualbox computer and run created pages there.

I guess I have to acces virtualbox computer via IP somehow. Another think is that I want to acces this webserver for everybody in the network, not just my computer. These clients could have both Linux and Windows OSs.

Could you anybody help me to figure out this stuff, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set the guest os network interface in virtualbox to bridged
2. networking. assign a static ip address that corresponds to your LAN
3. restart your web server (typically its sudo service apache2 restart)